# How to automatically redirect next jsp page when combo box value changed

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, html-select, dom-events

I am trying to automatically redirect to feedbackform.jsp from success.jsp, when combo box value change and send the selected value to feedbackform.jsp. But I am confused and not getting how to do it. What I have done till now -

This code is on success.jsp

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
        <h1><center>Feed Back System</center></h1>
        <center>
<%
if ((session.getAttribute("userid") == null) || (session.getAttribute("userid") == "")) {
%>
<font size='4' color='red'>You are not logged in</font><br/>
<a href="index.jsp">Please Login</a>
<%} else {
%>
<p class="member">Welcome <%=session.getAttribute("userid")%>, you are from semester <%=session.getAttribute("category")%></p>
<a href='logout.jsp'>Log out</a>
<%
    }
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/feedback","root", "");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs;
    rs = st.executeQuery("select * from faculty");
%>
<form method="post" name="myform" action="feedbackform.jsp">
<table width="480" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><font color="#00FFCC" size="4">Tip :- &ldquo;Select 1 for excellent 2 for better 3 for good 4 for poor&rdquo;</font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="151" class="member">Select Faculty</td>
    <td width="264" colspan="2"><select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
        <%  while(rs.next()){ %>
            <option><%= rs.getString(2)%></option>
        <% } %>
        </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        </center>
```

Now here I am stuck how can redirect when drop down "mySelect" value changes.
Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change myFunction() code in java script

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
var y = "your value";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com"; //redirect normally on changes

/* you can also check select value with condition and redirect like this 
if (X.toLowerCase() === y.toLowerCase())
{
  window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";
}
*/

}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you it worked, but how can I get this value->x on next jsp page. Like if I want to set this value in `String n=request.getParameter("val");
session.setAttribute("facname",n);` is this possible what I am thinking.

Comment: In next page String fname=session.getAttribute("facname")

Comment: OK I done it `window.location = "feedbackform.jsp?val="+x;` this is fine working